# Got error running existing react js app

Tags: reactjs

I am facing this error while running react js app. I already install current version of node js and npm.

~/Desktop/music/client
$ npm start

> client@1.0.0 start C:\Users\DIU\Desktop\music\client
>   ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --hot --progress --colors --inline --quiet --history-api-fallback

'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "start"
npm ERR! node v7.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! client@1.0.0 start: `./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --hot --progress --colors --inline --quiet --history-api-fallback`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the client@1.0.0 start script './node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --hot --progress --colors --inline --quiet --history-api-fallback'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the client package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --hot --progress --colors --inline --quiet --history-api-fallback
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs client
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls client
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\DIU\Desktop\music\client\npm-debug.log

Comment: How is your "start" command defined (package.json)?

Comment: Now it's working. I removed ./node_modules/ from the start command at package.json

Comment: I got another error. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\DIU\Desktop\music\client\dist\scripts\longtail-service-worker.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:558:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:1223:33)
    at C:\Users\DIU\Desktop\music\client\node_modules\sw-precache-webpack-plugin\lib\index.js:202:29

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
ctrl + Alt + Delete,
Task Manager,
Find all running instances of node server and kill them.
install your packages.

basic idea is that your node server keeps running in the background even after you think you've closed it in the console and it is accessing all your node files.